# Cone $CX$ is a $T4$ space

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological space. If $X\times[0,1]$ is $T_{4}$ then the cone $CX$ is $T_{3\frac{1}{2}}$.

I tried to prove this using the definition of $T_{3\frac{1}{2}}$ but I really don't see how to manipulate the closed sets of the cone $CX$. Also, I was trying to understand the cone $CX$ like a decomposition space (i.e. like a partition of the space $X$, maybe like $\{\{\{(x,t)\}:x\in X,t\in[0,1)\},X\times\{1\}\}$ equipped with the quotient topology). Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

P.D. This is an excercise of my last exam in my general topology course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an idea how to see that. I would use Lemma of Urysohn to get $4_{\frac{1}{2}}$. Now of you want to separate a closed set from a point in the cone, you can look at the preimage of those two sets under the projection map. With $T_2$ you get that the point is closed in the cone so the preimages are closed sets, as the projection map is continuous. There you can separate the with a function (Urysohn). And then you find a unique continuous function from the cone into $[0,1]$ that commutes with your first one and the projection map. This one separates the point from the closed set. Is it clear what I meant?

Comment: You're right. Using the universal property of quotient spaces and cheking that if $(x,1)\simeq (x',1)$ then they agree in the Urysohn function, the result follows. Thank you.

Comment: My only question is that, you don't know that the cone $CX$ is $T_{2}$ so, maybe you want to consider the set $\{q^{-1}([x])\}$ in $X\times [0,1]$ and here use that the space is $T_{1}$ so you can claim the set is closed.

Comment: But do you know, that $X\times[0,1]$ is $T_1$? By the way of course $T_1$ is enough, that all singeltons are closed, so $T_2$ can be replaced by $T_1$ in my answer.